# header search path issue

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just did a pull to a library that I am using in my project. There is a class called RKObjectLoaderTTModel that I would like to use (this is a new class from the pulled resource). However now it's giving me an:

> RKObjectLoaderTTModel undeclared
>   (first use in this function)

Why is this? I even tried including the RKObjectLoaderTTModel.h and it says that it couldn't find it

```
**UPDATE**
```

I think I know what the issue is. Inside the library there is a Build folder, and I removed all that file in the Build folder so that it would build from scratch. However, after building I didn't see any class called RKObjectLoaderTTModel inside the build. The question is, why isn't it building the RKObjectLoaderTTModel class? I know it exists in the Code folder

Answer (score 0):

Did you do #import --- for its declaration? this error happen since you are trying to access a unknown object interface.

Comment: yes I did, that's what I mean by including the .h and it can't find the .h as well

Comment: Just try following -- Make sure that you have include the file in source tree then you should have the #import of the declaration of the object interface. you can try a clean build in in xCode too.

Comment: Do you have multiple targets in the xCode? --- if so make sure you have added the file for right target.

Comment: Try making the header file you are using as public --- Set role as Public

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the restkit's headers to the header search path. 
In XCode4  you'll find this setting in project properties->Build Settings->Search Paths->Header Search Paths

Comment: I have that already in there, I can use RKObjectLoader just fine without any issue.. it's just that this new OM 2.0, there is RKObjectLoaderTTModel that I want to use, in which I can't access